# rails 3.2 and modifications on css file not reflecting until assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a new rails 3.2 project and everything is loading fine except the last modifications I made on css files.

If I do `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` change anything on this file, I can't see the changes on the browser until I run the following command at console:

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development`

my `config/environment/development.rb` file.

```
Sample::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you start your server in development mode or in production? Do you use the same port sometime for development, sometimes for production? Do you have done that before, to precompile the assets? I have noticed a similar behavior, and now have 2 repos, one for development and one for production to avoid that situation.

Comment: @mliebelt working only in development mode

Comment: Does it help if you stop and restart the server to see your changes? Never had this effect ... Could you add the configuration of `config/environments/development.rb` that are related to assets?

Comment: Just tried to restart and it doesn't work neither. I pasted my development file above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that I'd compiled the assets, so the rails was serving the already compiled version of these files.

In this case, all you have to do is, just delete the already generated files, like `application.css` and `application.css.gz` and you well get it working again.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I noticed the same and have now divided development and production: development without precompiled files, production with `assets:precompiled`. I think that is a bug, see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140447/best-deployment-strategy-for-local-used-application-in-rails-3-1-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

Running bundle `exec rake assets:clean` solves the problem. Also if you want to manually delete these files they are present in the app's public folder inside assets.

Comment: Thanks for shareing this. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an old thread, but I've found that sometimes a `rake assets:clean` won't take care of it in Rails 4.2.1. Sometimes, you need to use a stronger verb like clobber: `rake assets:clobber`